# Funny behaviour while executing a query in SOLR 6

Tags: curl, solr

something funny occured while measurement of Query response times:
After executing a query and restarting SOLR with 'bin/solr restart -all' (to clear cache) i found following funny behaviour.

If i reload the admin interface of SOLR after restart, the query response time decreased by roundabout 50ms. Can anybody explain that?

Sample Query with cURL: 'curl  -w \n%{time_starttransfer} -XGET "http://localhost:8983/solr/FOO/select?q=FIELD:%22foo%20bar%22&" && bin/solr restart -all'

Comment: Are you sure you are restarting the same servers your were running? Without *-s* flag, you are using the one under the *server* directory, not one of the example ones. Also, I do not believe *restart* command takes *-all* parameter, only the *stop* command.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, i'm sure the correct SOLR instance is restarting, therefore i execute this command in my _solr/server_ Directory.
Ohh yeah, you're right, _-all_ is redundant!